# Can you use a Swift DateFormatter to take a Date object, format it, and return it as a Date object?

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

I'm trying to format a `Date` object in Swift using `DateFormatter`. I'm grabbing a Date object from a UIDatePicker in the format 2020-09-04T10:19:26+0000, and I want to reformat it to 2020-09-04 10:19.

From what I understand, `DateFormatter` can only create a Date object from a string using the `date(from: String)` method, or a string from a Date object using `string(from: Date)`. Thus, for my seemingly simple use case, I would need two DateFormatters: One for converting my original date to a string, and a second one to format that string to my desired format and returning it as a Date object.

Is this really the "smart" way to re-format a Date object in Swift, or am I missing something?

edit:

I'm saving projects (which can have a due date) to a database. Later on, I plan on reading specific projects from the db based on their due date. The UIDatePicker returns an unformatted Date object (with seconds, offset and so on), but I only need the date, hour and minutes (exact to a 15 minute interval).

Comment: Date data type is not mean to be reformatted, because represent a point in time, and is universal, so Date object is always well formatted, you need to use one date format or another depending of what format of date you want to show

Comment: A Date object has no format it's just holds data for date and time. Keep your Date object from the DatePicker as a Date until you need to show it in the UI then you use a formatter to format it into string

Comment: How do you plan to use this "reformatted date"? That would be a good step to a good answer.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy Reformatting the date is pointless in this context. And to clarify to OP, the format you get when doing `print` or viewing a date object in the debugger is just a Date that has been formatted using a default format.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I do agree with you, but let's get the OP's answer.

Comment: use case: I'm saving projects (which can have a due date) to a database. Later on, I plan on reading specific projects from the db based on their due date. The UIDatePicker returns an unformatted Date object (with seconds, offset and so on), but I only need the date, hour and minutes (exact to a 15 minute interval).

Comment: @hwollersheim possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/60084423/2303865

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking about dates in the wrong way. The date is not a representation, but a fixed point in time, which can be represented in many ways, depending on how you write a date, and what timezone you're in. E.g. all of these can represent the exactly same point in time:

```
YYYY (eg 2020)
YYYY-MM (eg 2020-07)
YYYY-MM-DD (eg 2020-07-16)
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD (eg 2020-07-16T19:20+01:00)
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 2020-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 2020-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
```

So, if you would convert a `Date` to `String`, and then back to `Date`, you would usually get the same object back.

You need to note here that when starting from just a string, e.g. `2020-07-16T19:20`, this represents a different information depending on the current timeZone, the calendar etc on each different device. If you store this info in the database, you will cause a lot of time-based bugs, so you should avoid it at all costs.

The `Date` object returned from the datePicker is a point in time, and can be formatted to show that time in whatever format you prefer, so use that for representation purposes, and store the actual Date object in the database.

Comment: `YYYY` it is not the same as `yyyy`. `Y` is for year of week of year.

Comment: `hh` means 1-12 hours for 0-23 you need to use `HH`

Comment: `D` means day of year not day of the month `dd`

Comment: `s` is seconds for fractional seconds you need to use `SS`

Comment: T should be escaped and I don’t know what TZD means but for timezone with Z for UTC you should use `XXXXX`

Comment: Thanks, I don't plan on using any of them since they are just date examples and not dateFormatter formats.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

guard let inputTimeStamp = formatter.date(from: yourInputDate)?.timeIntervalSince1970 else { return }
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: inputTimeStamp)
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
let string = formatter.string(from: date)
```

Comment: Please read the question again **"and returning it as a Date object."**

Comment: This is not what is being asked here.

Comment: @LeoDabus should i remove this then? It is not what he looking for.