# Getting current time from datepicker if interval has set for datepicker in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

I am using date picker with time interval of 30 min. In datePicker it is showing properly with interval of 30. I am getting current time when I picked value from the picker. I am expecting it should be the selected value from the picker not the current time. I am using following code written in Swift 4.

```
func getTime(sender:UIDatePicker)
{
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    let endDate = (sender.date).addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(30.0 * 60.0))
    let time = dateFormatter.string(from: endDate)
    print(“time”) //getting current time like 8:14 AM , expected should be 8:00 AM
}
```

Comment: What time is shown in the date picker when this `getTime` function is called? When is this `getTime` function called?

Comment: I'm little confused what you want to do. You're have a date picker, you want when you picked (ex : 8:00 AM) you want to display 8:30 AM instead of 8:00AM ?
:

Comment: @TungVuDuc In datePicker it is showing properly with interval of 30 like 8, 8:30, 9 and so on. suppose current time is 8:14 which is in between 8 to 8:30. I picked 8 from picker. So it should return 8:00. But it is returning 8:14. It is giving current time, Expected is 8:00.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIDatePicker with 15m interval but always exact time as return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504060/uidatepicker-with-15m-interval-but-always-exact-time-as-return-value)

Answer (score 5):

You can get the time from `DatePicker` based on what you select. But you have to get the initial time rounded off to next interval hour by yourself. You can see the code below it will help you.

> In this method we are adding target to the `datepicker` to get the time based on our selection and we are also getting the initial time.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let currentTime = Date()
    let interval = 30
    self.getInitialTime(currentTime: currentTime, interval: interval)
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(getTime(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
}
```

> This function will calculate the time rounded off to next interval time.

```
func getInitialTime(currentTime: Date, interval: Int) {
    var components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.minute, .hour], from: currentTime)
    let minute = components.minute
    let remainder = ceil(Float(minute!/interval))
    let finalMinutes = Int(remainder * Float(interval)) + interval
    components.setValue(finalMinutes, for: .minute)
    guard let finalTime = Calendar.current.date(from: components) else { return }
    self.getDate(date: finalTime)
}
```

> In these methods we are calling another function which converts date to the required format.

```
@objc func getTime(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    self.getDate(date: sender.date)
}

func getDate(date: Date) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = DateFormatter.Style.short
    dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    let time = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(time)
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is for extract date form date picker:

```swift
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
date = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
```

And this is for extract time from date picker:

```swift
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
timePicker.datePickerMode = .time
var ouptputTime = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
```

The most important thing is formatting string. ex("hh:mm:ss a")

Answer (score -2):

I think this will be helpful.

```
func getTime(sender:UIDatePicker)
{
    var dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
    var ouptputTime = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
    print("ouptputTime:-\(ouptputTime)")
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this is helpful? How does this fix the issue? This simply changes how the date is formatted. But there is no problem with how the date is formatted.